# inner product of two random vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-variables, vectors

Two random vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$. Vector $\mathbf a$ has uncorrelated entries satisfying $\mathbb E [\mathbf a \mathbf a^{\rm H}]=\sigma^2{\mathbf I}$. Now I need to calculate ${\mathbb E} [|\mathbf b^{\rm H} \mathbf a|^2]$.

For ***independent*** $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, it can be calculated as
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E} [|\mathbf b^{\rm H} \mathbf a|^2]&=\mathbb E [\mathbf b^{\rm H} \mathbf a \mathbf a^{\rm H} \mathbf b]\\
&={\mathbb E} \big[\mathbf b^{\rm H} {\mathbb E} [\mathbf a \mathbf a^{\rm H}] \mathbf b\big]\\
&=\sigma^2\|\mathbf b\|^2.
\end{align}
The second equation uses the independence of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$.

My question is, if $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are **not** independent, can the above equation serve as an upper bound?

Any help appreciated! : )

Comment: Could you post an edit explaining the notation? I've never seen the $\mathbb{E}$ you're using, and I'm not sure what the $H$ in the exponent or the $\sigma$ are supposed to mean.

Comment: @mathers101 This is all common statistics notation (with the exception of $H$). $\mathbb{E}$ is the expected value. $\sigma^2$ (for the purposes of this problem) is a constant greater than $0$. $H$ is likely the [Hermitian Transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).

Comment: @Clarinetist okay thanks. I was wondering why I didn't understand any of it, I've never done any statistics.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation calculation for independent $a$ and $b$ is incorrect (you can't pass expected value calculations for vectors through in the same way as you do for scalars); however, the final result is the upper bound for the expected value.  Intuitively, you will get the highest value when $a$ and $b$ have to be in the same direction, and the stated end result is the correct expected value for this case.  However, $a$ and $b$ will certainly not be independent in this case.